# Understanding Map Document Properties?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, mxd

You set up your mxd in a folder.  However, when you copy and paste to a different folder, the Map Document Properties does not update the document path when you save a new mxd with a different title. It brings to the new folder from the previous folder ? I want to change that and how do I do that ?

Comment: generally you don't want to copy/paste mxd documents. (arcmap/arcview has never liked that). There is a save, saveas, and save copy that would help alleviate the problems you are having with the path.

Comment: i'm using 10.2.2. the Map Document Properties updates whether I "Save As" or copy/paste like a regular file. Are you meaning the *data* remains pointed at the old path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your talking about using relative paths.

You can set the MXD to use relative paths by going to **File** ---> **Map Document Properties** and checking the *Store relative pathnames to data sources*:

[image]

If you want this to be the default setting for all new MXDs, you can go into the **Customize menu** ---> **ArcMap Options** and on the General tab check the *Make relative paths the default for new map documents*:

[image]